# MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT HSTS in https site

Tags: apache, google-chrome, firefox, laravel-5, ssl-certificate

I downloaded a project on localhost via bitbucket, I set up a virtual host but I have an error on each browser that the certificate is self-signed. I created the certificate in xampp and added it to trusted certificates in the chrome / windows 10 settings and unfortunately I still have the same error.

The project is on laravel 5 and in env file, I set the `http` and `APP_DEV` domain to local.

My virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\project\public"
    ServerName project.app
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "E:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "E:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key"
    <Directory "E:\xampp\htdocs\project\public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to run a project via virtual host on laravel 5. Unfortunately, I still have the error HSTS `MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT` on Firefox, and `NET :: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` on Chrome.
I will add that I only want to run the project locally on the localhost, therefore no certificate is needed here, but the browser blocks

Comment: probably this issue is because of improper creation of the cerfificate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Get SSL Certificate to Work With Localhost on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101097/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-to-work-with-localhost-on-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

This error related to .app, .dev TLD.Chromium forced all domains with the .app,.dev TLD to only respond to secure connections